# Can I force IE9 to Internet Explorer 9 standard mode

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode, strict

When i browse one site my IE9 is set in Quirks Mode:

I put in my header's site `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1` but nothing change.

My doctype is "Strict".

Help me please :(

Answer (score 6):

Just to cover our bases, have you added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the head of your document?

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that should be the only necessary change to put IE9 into standards mode. If you do not have the !Doctype directive, then IE9 will go into IE5 mode!(Quirks) .. so make sure you have it!

Comment: i have set this DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd

Comment: ok problem resolve... I add <!DOCTYPE html> and move up meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" as second meta tag ^^ thnx

Comment: ok, then mark this as the correct answer, thanks because that is what I said to do.